# Nesting queries much slower than each individual query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a query that uses a list of ids extracted from another query. Each of the individual queries is fast enough for my purpose (under 0.5 seconds) but the combined one is very slow.

This first query is getting a list of ids, and it takes 0.2 seconds:

```
select distinct column1 
    from table1 where id in
    (select id from table2 where match(column3) against('keyword' in boolean mode)) 
    limit 10000000;
```

The second query, now using the list of ids, parsed manually from the first query, takes 0.16 seconds:

```
select * from table3 where id in (
    -- list of ids parsed manually
) limit 10000000;
```

But when I combine the two queries together it runs for over 6 minutes. Here's the combined query:

```
select * from table3 where id in (
    select distinct column 
        from table1 where id in
        (select id from table2 where match(column3) against('keyword' in boolean mode))
) limit 10000000;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to speed up these exact queries.  But if you could rephrase them as a series of joins you might be able to use indices.

Comment: Well the actual queries are fast enough for me. It's the nesting of the 1st inside the 2nd that creates the problem.